# Apply opacity to Slider

Tags: html, css, slider

Good evening, I'm a novice at applying styles, well my problem is that I have the following slider, and I want to add opacity to it.

```
<div class="single-hero-slide bg-img" style="background-image: url(img/slider/slider4.jpg);">
                <div class="container h-100">
                    <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="hero-slides-content">
                                <h4 data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="100ms">All the courses you need</h4>
                                <h2 data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="400ms">Wellcome to our <br>Online University</h2>
                                <a href="#" class="btn academy-btn" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-delay="700ms">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I would like you to help me with the css code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend inline styles which is what you have included, as it's not maintainable. To add a css file to your project make a new css file (preferable called `main.css` and then link to it using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="*">` Paste this code in to the header of your html and then change the * to the file location. Next you can reference the slider classes, in your case you would type `.container h-100{}` and then within the curly braces type `opacity: ;` and in between : & ; write
any number on a scale of 0 ~ 1. An opacity of 0 will be invisible and an opacity of 1 will be completely visible. Hope this answered your question!